# How to prevent html from being rendered until after $http call?

Tags: angularjs

So in my "articles" example from the MeanJS boilerplate, I added a comments function. The problem is, is that I have to make a separate call to an API endpoint on the server side to load the comments. I was wondering if it is possible to prevent the HTML that contains the comments from being loaded until *after* the $http call is finished? Where can I find resources on how to do this? I have tried ng-if, and the element in which the comments reside already has a `data-ng-init`.

Comment: set a boolean and an ng-if that triggers in the return of the call. Would be helpful if you showed a little code, maybe what you have tried here.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
app.controller("commentCtrl",function($scope,$http){

   $scope.isCommentLoaded=false;

   $http.get('/path/to/your/comment/api').then(function(result){
        $scope.comments=result.data;
        $scope.isCommentLoaded=true;
   });

});
```

and then in your HTML:

```
<div id="comments" ng-show="isCommentLoaded">
    ....Your HTML to show comments....
</div>
```